# Converting an unknown text format into a dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, text

I have just scraped some response text from inspect element, but it is in a format I'm unfamiliar with. (i.e, not JSON or HTML etc).
The text in a format like this.

```
 ({:a 186, :b 4, :c "l", :a 6, :b 93, :c "e"})
```

I'd like to create a dataframe, with columns names using the character after the `:` and the string after the space being rows of that column.

example,

```
a    b   c
_    _   _
186  4   l
6    93  e
```

what would be the best way to do this in python?

Comment: _"what would be the best way to do this"_ - Reverse engineer the syntax and grammar of the data format.  You'll probably need a lot more data than that.  _"in python"_  - Write some code?

Answer (score 0):

Have to make a lot of assumptions about the format of your data, but with your example you could get away with using `re(gex)` to capture the "keys" and "values" and then do some data manipulation using `pandas`.

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

data = '({:a 186, :b 4, :c "l", :a 6, :b 93, :c "e"})'

# match the patterns to separate "keys" and "values"
pattern = r'\:([a-z])\s"?(\d+|[a-z])"?'
matches = re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=data)
print(matches)
```

```
[('a', '186'), ('b', '4'), ('c', 'l'), ('a', '6'), ('b', '93'), ('c', 'e')]
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(matches)
# combine the "values" into a list per "key"
df = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
# expand the values into their own columns and transpose
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df.to_list(), index=df.index).T
print(df)
```

```
0    a   b  c
0  186   4  l
1    6  93  e
```